# Delete member of struct on heap after std::move()

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct, memory-leaks

I'm currently refactoring and change existing code to C++11 and I wonder if have memory leak. My code has a struct with a `std::vector` in it as well as a method to `shrink()` this vector down to its negative elements.

```
struct mystruct_t {

    int other_stuff;

    std::vector <int> loc;

    // Adds elements to loc vector
    void add(int pos){
        loc.push_back(pos);
    }

    // Shrink the list 
    void shrink () {
        std::vector<int> tmp;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < loc.size(); ++i) {
            if (loc[i] < 0) tmp.push_back (loc[i]);
        }
        loc = tmp;
        std::vector<int>(loc).swap (loc);
    }

    mystruct_t(): otherstuff(0) {};
};
```

In another function I create a new instance of this struct like this:

```
mystruct_t c = new mystruct_t;
c->add(2);
c->add(3);
...
```

And later I call the `shrink()` method of this struct.

```
c->shrink()
```

**Now I'm not sure what's happening with the "old" loc vector after the shrink function?**
Will it get destroyed automatically or do I have to destroyed by hand? And if the later, how would I do that?

I also tried to change `shrink()` to more C++11 style by change it to:

```
void shrink (){        
    std::vector<int> tmp;
    for (auto &currLoc : loc) {
        if (currLoc < 0) tmp.push_back (currLoc);
    }
    loc = std::move(tmp);
}
```

But the question remains the same what is happening to the "old" loc vector additionally this seems to increase the memory usage. I'm new to C++11 and not sure if I totally misunderstand the concept?

Comment: `std::vector<int>(loc).swap (loc);` what's the point of this?

Comment: @Holt It is a guaranteed `shrink_to_fit` since `shrink_to_fit` is not required to actually do anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver Wouldn't `loc.swap(tmp)` be an easier way of doing that?

Comment: @juanchopanza No because `tmp` could have more capacity then it needs.  The OP is trying to shrink the capacity of that created vector(at least I think they are) so it takes up the minimal amount of space required.  `loc.swap(tmp)` can replace the `loc = tmp;` though.

Comment: Or even simpler: `std::vector<int>(tmp).swap (loc);`

Comment: Or use the erase and remove idiom and then shrink the container.

Comment: @NathanOliver ^^^^^^^^ +1; easiest approach, and just skip the shrinking if you don't run out of RAM.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I agree.  In most casaes there is not a reason to shrink the vector.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes exactly, I would like that `loc` after `shrink()` only occupies the space it really needs since there will be a lot of elements removed. Favorable without copying anything. Is this shrinking of the capacity also the problem of the C++11 approach?

Comment: @svgspnr You are going to have to copy if you want to shrink the storage.  My advice is to use the erase and remove idiom so you do not have to construct a temporary vector.  Then I would then leave the capacity alone.  Unless you are really pressed for memory(the vector is **huge**) then it should not be a problem at it will save you CPU cycles.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't see how it's a guaranteed `shrink_to_fit`. There's nothing preventing an implementation from copy constructing based on the capacity of the original `vector`. `std::vector<int>(loc.begin(), loc.end()).swap(loc)` is probably better, but really, don't bother with all this unless you cannot afford to keep using that extra memory, just erase-remove and forget about it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, would it look like this with the erase and remove idiom:
`loc.erase( std::remove_if(loc.begin(), loc.end(), [](int i){return i >= 0;}),loc.end());` - Edited.

Comment: Looks good except it should be `return i >= 0;` according to the logic in the question.

Comment: @Praetorian You know I think you are right.  I think it would be silly for an implementation to do that but I can't find anything that says they can't.  I would use the iterator approach if you really want the guarantee, but as you and I have said the shrink really shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @Praetorian I will try it with erase-remove for now but since the vector might get quite big and especially big difference of number when shrinkt or nor. Additionally I will have plenty of them. I might have to come back to the capacity adjustment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I'm not sure what's happening with the "old" loc vector after the shrink function?

There is no "old" `loc` vector. Through the lifetime of a `mystruct_t` object, it has exactly one member vector `loc`. You never get a new member or throw away an old one.

When you copy assign to the member (`loc = tmp;`), the buffer - cotained within the vector - is renewed. The vector owns the buffer, and the vector takes care that it is destroyed properly. Same applies when you move assign in the c++11 version.

> Will it get destroyed automatically

If you refer to the memory allocated by the vector, then yes.

> or do I have to destroyed by hand?

You have to destroy by hand only whatever you created by hand. You didn't call `new`, so you don't call `delete`.

---

> additionally this seems to increase the memory usage.

Your c++11 version lacks the "shrink to fit" part of the original (`std::vector<int>(loc).swap (loc);`). In c++11 you can do:

```
loc = std::move(tmp);
loc.shrink_to_fit();
```

In the pre c++11 version, can get rid of the copy assignment and simply construct the temporary from `tmp`, and swap it with `loc`:

```
std::vector<int> tmp;
// copy the objects you want
std::vector<int>(tmp).swap(loc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Operation `std::move` just casting values, so there is no additional memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `std::move` compiler will remove `head address` of first object, and just reassign memory to second object. So it's very fast operation, etc just changing the `head` of data.